# How to POST data to Google Analytics with VB6

Tags: vb6, google-analytics

We have an ancient VB6 component that needs Google Analytics tracking.  I am using the Internet Transfer Control to POST data via HTTP.  I cannot see my tracking data in the Google Analytics reports.  This leads me to believe that I cam calling POST incorrectly.

I have already added Google Analytics tracking to a desktop .Net Application and can see that data so I know it works.

I have a VB6 form with a button on it.  The button-click event executes:

```
Dim var1 As String
var1 = "v=1&tid=UA-00000000-1&cid=123&t=appview&cd=VBScreen"
Inet1.Execute "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", "POST", var1
```

This doesn't return an error but no data can be seen in the Google Analytics reporting pages.  What am I going wrong?

I do not need to use the Internet Transfer Control if there is some other simple way to do this.

After Execute() is called, Inet1_StateChanged is fired and the state is icResponseCompleted.  Inet1.ResponseInfo == "" and Inet1.StillExecuting == False.

Comment: Print out Inet1.ResponseInfo and Inet1.StillExecuting

Comment: added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall why the original code did not work, but I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
Dim xmlhttp As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set xmlhttp = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Dim var1 As String
var1 = "v=1&tid=UA-00000000-0&cid=123&an=MyAN&av=1.0&t=event&ec=ecData&ea=eaData&el=elData"

xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", False
xmlhttp.send var1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```